# Wagtail / CodeRedCMS: jQuery ReferenceError $ is not defined, can't determine reason why

Tags: jquery, html, django, twitter-bootstrap, wagtail

I'm using CodeRedCMS which is built on Wagtail (which is built on Django), and I can clearly see that jQuery is properly getting imported into each page, however when trying to access my flipclock.js function I'm getting a ReferenceError and the clock isn't loading.

**HTML module in Wagtail Admin page:**

```html
<div class="clock"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var clock;

$(document).ready(function() {

                // Grab the current date
                var currentDate = new Date();

                // Set some date in the future. In this case, it's always Jan 1
                var futureDate  = new Date(currentDate.getFullYear() + 1, 0, 1);

                // Calculate the difference in seconds between the future and current date
                var diff = futureDate.getTime() / 1000 - currentDate.getTime() / 1000;

                // Instantiate a coutdown FlipClock
                clock = $('.clock').FlipClock(diff, {
                    clockFace: 'DailyCounter',
                    countdown: true
                });
            });
</script>
```

**Base.html:**

```html
{% extends "coderedcms/pages/base.html" %}
{% load static %}

{% block custom_assets %}
{# Add your custom CSS here #}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'website/css/custom.css' %}">
{% endblock %}

{% block custom_scripts %}
{# Add your custom JavaScript here, or delete the line below if you don't need any #}
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'website/js/custom.js' %}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'website/js/flipclock.min.js' %}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

CodeRedCMS automatically imports Bootstrap and jQuery, I can see it loading in the console when the webpage loads.

Any ideas?  I can't imagine that the custom assets and scripts are being loaded in before jQuery/Bootstrap so I don't think that's the issue.

Comment: Does it work if you replace `$` with `jQuery`?

Comment: @stasiekz or `window.jQuery` ?

Comment: @stasiekz @bassxzero Tried that, for `jQuery` I get `jQuery is not defined`.  for `window.jQuery` I get `window.jQuery is not a function`

Comment: As an additional verification that CodeRed is importing jQuery, I imported it into my base template, still the same issue.

Comment: Make sure you have jQuery loaded before your custom JavaScript is being loaded in the Dom. Always good to double check that and verify. If the order is correct, try giving your page a hard refresh, sometimes browser caching is a troublemaker. If it's not that, open your browser console and refresh the page and look for loading errors.